# Ionic 3 show first 10 array then after scroll 10

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I need to know i am fetching data from api. I need to show first 10 array. Then when user scroll then show 10 like this . How can i do this ?

```
this.item = this.http.get('https://afaq-manda.com/api/');


this.item.subscribe(data => {
    loading.dismiss();

 this.data = data;
  console.log('my data: ', this.data);
})
```

This is how i am fetching data. Thanks

Comment: You can use pagination for that

Answer (score 1):

**YOU CAN DO IT TWO WAYS**

> Infinite Scroll Content
>   [infinite-scroll-content](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/infinite-scroll#infinite-scroll-content)

The `ion-infinite-scroll` component has the infinite scroll logic. It requires a child component in order to display content. Ionic uses its `ion-infinite-scroll-content` component by default. This component displays the infinite scroll and changes the look depending on the infinite scroll's state. It displays a spinner that looks best based on the platform the user is on. However, the default spinner can be changed and text can be added by setting properties on the `ion-infinite-scroll-content` component.

> IN IONIC VIEW

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-button (click)="toggleInfiniteScroll()" expand="block">
    Toggle Infinite Scroll
  </ion-button>

  <ion-list></ion-list>

  <ion-infinite-scroll threshold="100px" (ionInfinite)="loadData($event)">
    <ion-infinite-scroll-content
      loadingSpinner="bubbles"
      loadingText="Loading more data...">
    </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
  </ion-infinite-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

> in .ts

```
 import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
    import { IonInfiniteScroll } from '@ionic/angular';

    @Component({
      selector: 'infinite-scroll-example',
      templateUrl: 'infinite-scroll-example.html',
      styleUrls: ['./infinite-scroll-example.css']
    })
    export class InfiniteScrollExample {
      @ViewChild(IonInfiniteScroll) infiniteScroll: IonInfiniteScroll;

      constructor() {}

      loadData(event) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log('Done');
          event.target.complete();

          // App logic to determine if all data is loaded
          // and disable the infinite scroll
          if (data.length == 1000) {
            event.target.disabled = true;
          }
        }, 500);
      }

      toggleInfiniteScroll() {
        this.infiniteScroll.disabled = !this.infiniteScroll.disabled;
      }

}
```

**Second way**

ngx-pagination

Simple Example

> app.module.ts

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgxPaginationModule} from 'ngx-pagination'; // <-- import the module
import {MyComponent} from './my.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, NgxPaginationModule], // <-- include it in your app module
    declarations: [MyComponent],
    bootstrap: [MyComponent]
})
export class MyAppModule {}
```

> my.component.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    template: `
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let item of collection | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: p }"> ... </li>
    </ul>

    <pagination-controls (pageChange)="p = $event"></pagination-controls>
    `
})
export class MyComponent {
    p: number = 1;
    collection: any[] = someArrayOfThings;  
}
```

[ngx-pagination](https://github.com/michaelbromley/ngx-pagination)

Answer (score 0):

You can use infinite-scroll for this.
HTML:

```
  <ion-list>
   <ion-item *ngFor="let i of itemsToDisplay">{{i}}</ion-item>
 </ion-list>
    <ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)">
       <ion-infinite-scroll-content></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
     </ion-infinite-scroll>
```

Component:

```
   itemsToDisplay =[];
    ngOnInit()
    {
     this.item = this.http.get('https://afaq-manda.com/api/');
     this.item.subscribe(data => {
      this.data = data;
      for(let i=0; i< 10; i++)
      {
       this.itemsToDisplay.push(this.data[i]);
      }
     })
    }

    doinfinite(){
     let len = this.itemsToDisplay.length;
     for(let i=len ; i< len+10; i++)
     {
       this.itemsToDisplay.push(this.data[i]);
     }
   }
```

Please refer this:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/components/infinite-scroll/InfiniteScroll/